# no-blocking server and thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I have a server which use one thread to receive UDP DatagramPackets from a remote data source; and a TCP ServerSocket to listen to remote clients request and spawn a dedicated thread for each client. 
I want to transfer each DatagramPackets through the ServerSocket to the multiple clients. And now i encountered significant packet loss. Could anybody give some advice? 
Thanks in advance。

Comment: Where (between server and data source or server and clients) and in which direction are you experiencing this significant packet loss?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be just wrong choice of protocols in design ? 
Something supposed to be reliable for multiple clients, as you use TCP. But reliability failed because of introduced dependency on UDP trough coupling (bridging/rebroadcasting) on server side.

UDP is more or less applicable for reliable applications, if you take into account that packets will be lost by design.

- Solution 1: change protocol
- Solution 2: if not possible to change protocol, then change expectations of user on client side about quality of service
- Solution 3: add redundancy to UDP side to repeat requests, stock data ahead of time expecting future drops of quality, maintain large accumulated cache of data to feed clients no matter what.

Comment: 4. Re-implement TCP over UDP O.o

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am afraid it's a typical producer-consumer problem in multi-thread programming. And now i am struggling with it. Any guideline is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more to the point to get rid of UDP *at the sender* rather than try to shoehorn it somehow into your TCP design at the receiver, where it is already too late. The packets are lost between the sender and receiver, not in your receiver. Fixing the receiver code won't fix the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your application design, I can make the following guesses:

- Your UDP source is sending more packets than your receiver can handle causing packets to be dropped, because
- your receiver is being blocked when passing off the packets to the TCP clients, because
- your TCP clients are not picking up the packets quickly enough causing the buffer to fill up (which forces the server to block which causes it to miss UDP packets).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have located the cause of the packet loss, and it's just as you've said. The receive buffer is shared by the UDP receive thread and the TCP send thread, which results in packet loss if the sending threads don't complete the  sending process before the new packets coming. I have tried wait-notify mechanism to schedule these write and read threads, but it comes into dead lock easily.  Since i don't have much multi-threading programming experience, i don't know whether there are some other mechanism. Could you please give some suggestion? Great thanks!

Comment: @Xu DXn: Try using something like a [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) or [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).  Maybe one queue per TCP connection. But you'll have to deal with the possibility that you are receiving more UDP packets than one or more of your TCP clients can cope with and decide which ones you'll discard.